# tree.nodeSize() not working in D3 tree graph to inc. the space between nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I wanted to inc the space between nodes vertically and for that I find out that d3 have `nodeSize()` from v3 onward , I find out similar questions on stack and fuddles and there everything works fine. But in my case this `nodeSize()` is not working.

I have created a js fiddle which includes my code but d3 graph is not exactly the same as i have in my dev server bec that includes angular and js calls too but I think that will not affect this size problem . So you can get an idea what I did and why `nodeSize()` is not working

http://jsfiddle.net/9428byn7/

Edited :

I just find out that nodeSize is also not working in their example http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033

may be bec they are using viewHieght and viewWidth , any solution ?

Comment: your comment at https://gist.github.com/robschmuecker/7880033#gistcomment-1583574 makes me think this http://jsfiddle.net/9428byn7/3/ might help not real sure what you are building but you mentioned the bootbox does not work...Good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok if you read the document:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout#size
Its states clearly in the doc:
*The size property is exclusive with tree.nodeSize; setting tree.size sets tree.nodeSize to null.*

So in your update function in the fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/9428byn7/) check line 473:
You have written:

```
tree = tree.size([newHeight, viewerWidth]);
```

Which nullifies your tree.nodeSize as per doc and as we are seeing it.
so instead of doing the above line instead do:

```
tree.nodeSize([200,600]);
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/9428byn7/1/).

Hope this clarifies your concern!

Comment: Yes , Update function too includes tree.size() , initially I searched for .size() in my file but didn't notice there are two instances of this . Anyway my mistake but thanks a lot , seriously you saved my day