# Centering of d3 tree changes when specifying nodeSize

Tags: d3.js

I'm using d3.v4 for this. When I have

```
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width])
```

the tree is nicely centred

[image]

but (because I want to specify the vertical spacing between nodes) when I change this to

```
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]).nodeSize([40]);
```

the tree moves to the top left:

[image]

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that `d3.tree().size()` and `d3.tree().nodeSize()` are exclusive in relation to one another. Setting one nullifies the other. The v3 documentation ([here](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Tree-Layout.md#size)) is explicit in this regard, while the v4 documentation ([here](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#tree))  might suggest that this is still true. Quick testing suggests v4 is the same as v3 in regards to this. (see also: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558649/d3-tree-layout-separation-between-nodes-using-nodesize), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32839957/tree-nodesize-not-working-in-d3-tree-graph-to-inc-the-space-between-nodeshttp://).)

More importantly, "When a node size is specified, the root node is always positioned at ⟨0, 0⟩." ([API documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#tree)).

When using `size`, the positioning of each node takes advantage of available space - positioning in relation to the specified width/height with no consideration for node density. When using `nodeSize`, positioning is relative to other nodes, not the available area for the diagram (though it will be anchored at [0,0]). By initially using `.size`, you didn't have to worry about positioning. Using `.nodeSize`, you'll have to set a transform for your nodes so that they are centered properly.

To position it properly, you'll need to set a transform on your container so that [0,0], and the root node, is more appropriately placed (as in the margin-less example below, at [0,height/2]):

```js
var data = { "name": "Parent", "children": [ { "name": "Child A", "children": [ { "name": "Grandchild" } ] }, { "name": "Child B", } ] };

var width = 500;
var height = 500;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);
      
var g = svg.append("g").attr('transform','translate(0,'+ (height/2) +')');
var root = d3.hierarchy(data);
      
var tree = d3.tree()
    .nodeSize([width/2,height/2]);

 var link = g.selectAll(".link")
    .data(tree(root).links())
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", d3.linkHorizontal()
          .x(function(d) { return d.y; })
          .y(function(d) { return d.x; }));

  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
    .data(root.descendants())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 2.5);
```

```css
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
svg {
    background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

As compared with the automatic spacing of `d3.tree().size()`:

```js
var data = { "name": "Parent", "children": [ { "name": "Child A", "children": [ { "name": "Grandchild" } ] }, { "name": "Child B", } ] };

var width = 500;
var height = 500;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);
      
var g = svg.append("g");
var root = d3.hierarchy(data);
      
var tree = d3.tree()
    .size([width,height]);

 var link = g.selectAll(".link")
    .data(tree(root).links())
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", d3.linkHorizontal()
          .x(function(d) { return d.y; })
          .y(function(d) { return d.x; }));

  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
    .data(root.descendants())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 2.5);
```

```css
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
svg {
    background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good answer, +1. D3 v4 API should be explicit about that, as in v3.

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest way to do it is **

```
        document.getElementById("wkgrp").style.transform = "translate(100px, 350px)"
```

set transform on load as per requirement, so it can dynamically manage by svg.